# Parameterized families of functions, other than neural networks, that are useful for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I think neural networks can be viewed as being merely a large parameterized family of functions. There are enough parameters that neural networks are "universal approximators", and yet neural networks are simple enough that they can be trained efficiently.

Are there any other parameterized families of functions, besides the neural network family, which have similar expressiveness and simplicity and so could be useful in machine learning as a substitute or alternative for neural networks?

Comment: What do you mean with the *neural network family*? Backpropagation for example can minimize the errors wrt any differentiable function through the chain rule. Is not the set of differentiable functions large enough?

Comment: A neural network is a particular type of function, right? The set of all functions of this special type is what I'm calling the "neural network family" of functions.

Comment: @mathreadler In machine learning we need a parameterized family of functions so that we can tune the parameters to find a function that explains our training data well. The set of all differentiable functions is not a parameterized family of functions, so I think it can't be used in this way for regression or classification problems.

Comment: It has some predetermined structure - a linear transformation of activation functions outputs, so it is more like a functional of the activation functions than a function. Ah I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An important family of distributions in machine learning is an **exponential family**. A pdf or pmf $p(x|\theta)$ for $x=(x_1,...,x_m) \in \cal X^{m}$ and $\theta \in \Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{d}$ is in the exponential family if it's in the form:
\begin{equation}
p(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{Z(\theta)}h(x)\exp[\theta^{T}\phi(x)] = h(x)\exp[\theta^{T}\phi(x) - A(\theta)]
\end{equation}
where $\theta$ represents natural parameters, $\phi(x)$ is a vector of sufficient statistics, and $Z(\theta)$ is the partition function. The exponential family is important for many reasons:

- Conjugate likelihood and prior that simplifies posterior computation in Bayesian algorithms
- Finite-sized sufficient statistics that enables summarization without loss of information
- Makes the least set of assumptions subject to user-chosen constraints

Some of the examples of exponential family distributions are Bernoulli, Dirichlet, Gaussian, Exponential distributions. Some non-examples include uniform and Student-T distributions.